# How to perform stream and map in List of String Arrays in Java?

Tags: java

Below is the my input:

```
List<String[]> items = List.of(
   new String[] {"Apple", "20"},
   new String[] {"Orange", "15"},
 new String[] {"Tomato", "25"} 

);
```

My expected output also should be in List of String Arrays :

```
"fruits", "35"
"vegetables", "25"
```

Will I be able to achieve this using maps and streams?

I know how to do stream and map on List of String, but could not do it on List of String Array.

```
eg:
  List<String> newItem = items.stream().map(item -> switch(item){
            case "Apple", "Orange" -> "fruits" ;
            case "Tomato" -> "vegetables" ;
            default -> "other";
        }).collect(Collectors.toList()) ;
```

Can you please help me achieve the solution?

Comment: `switch (item[0])`. Or, `.map(item -> item[0]).map(item -> switch (item) ...`.

Comment: @Mithil How do you identify whether you have a vegetable or fruit? what is your assumption there? your arrays are just arrays of strings, which is a bad design, in this case.

Comment: @AndyTurner: I tried the same as below.   But getting incompatible type error:  List<String[]> newArray = sampleArray.stream().map(s -> switch(s[0]){
            case "Apple", "Orange" -> "fruit" ;
            case "Tomato" -> "veg" ;
            default -> "other";
        }).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> new String(s[0]), Collectors.summingInt(s -> Integer.parseInt(s[1])))) ;

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri:  this is just a sample data,  my requirement is something different, which i have to achieve using streams, map and List of String Array

Comment: "*this is just a sample data*" - that's what I'm saying. This is a sample data.. hence we can't count on your string literals' being statically fixed inputs. Therefore, you need some way to identify whether an entry is a fruit, or vegetable. I suggest you incorporate your custom type, like `Product` or whatever you prefer.

Comment: *@AndyTurner: I tried the same as below. But getting incompatible type error:*  That was not what you asked. You changed the question in a comment.  Where did you mention `Collectors.summingInt()` in the original question?  You should edit your question and explain what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solution uses [`Collectors::toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.function.Supplier-) with merge function and `Supplier<Map>`:

```java
List<String[]> items = List.of(
    new String[] {"Apple", "20"},
    new String[] {"Orange", "15"},
    new String[] {"Potato", "25"} 
);

List<String[]> total = new ArrayList<>(items
    .stream()
    .map(arr -> new String[] {
        switch(arr[0]) {
            case "Apple", "Orange", "Tomato" -> "fruit";
            case "Potato" -> "vegetable";
            default -> "other";
        },
        arr[1]
    }) // create new array with the category and amount
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        arr -> arr[0],
        arr -> arr,
        (a1, a2) -> { 
            a1[1] = String.valueOf(
                Integer.parseInt(a1[1]) + Integer.parseInt(a2[1])
            );
            return a1;  
        },
        LinkedHashMap::new
    ))
    .values() // Collection<List<String[]>>
);

total.stream()
     .map(Arrays::toString)
     .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
[fruit, 35]
[vegetable, 25]
```

*Note: replaced `Tomato` in the input with `Potato` because [tomatoes are fruits which are considered vegetables by nutritionists](https://www.britannica.com/story/is-a-tomato-a-fruit-or-a-vegetable) :)*

[Online demo at Paiza](https://paiza.io/projects/j0mNTvUvnhaDjXCy0tcyLA?language=java)

Comment: Your answer prints `[fruit, 60]`.  You need to change the input data to include a potato (or change the output in your answer).

Comment: Amazing @Alex.   Didnt know that we can do these many miracles with Stream.   Thanks a lot.

Comment: @WJS, it was mentioned that `Tomato` was replaced with `Potato` :)  Anyway, updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

Several things in your posted answer.

- In each of the switch clauses, you need to return an array with both food category and value so you know what to sum. There are different ways to do that. Here's one example:

```
case "Apple", "Orange" -> new String[] {"fruit", s[1]};
```

- the first argument to your collector needs to now be `s -> s[0]` as the key to the map. It would then look like this:

```
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s[0],
        Collectors.summingInt(str -> Integer.parseInt(str[1]))));
```

- then you need to collect the entries into a `List<String[]>`.  You can do that by applying this to the end of your Collector.

```
.entrySet().stream()
           .map(e -> new String[] {e.getKey(), Integer.toString(e.getValue()) })
           .toList();
```